# How to display the image to be in transparent and clickable?

Tags: css, cakephp

I have a transparent .png image file which I have attached it on my site, however the file has some background colour (grey) which I have no understanding why it is there. It's sure in transparent mode when I open it in any image editor or view, it has transparent background. Why when I link it, and when displaying on my site it isn't transparent ?

This is the method I'm using http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1441/image

I've tried embedding the image in CSS but find it a bit troublesome because I need the image to be clickable that links to my homepage.

Anyone can suggest any way to achieve the result I mentioned? ..perhaps some links or scripts that would work..I appreciate that.

:-)

Comment: The fact you're using CakePHP has nothing to do with this really, it will be a CSS issue. Please provide an example of the image/CSS you're using.

Comment: Sorry should have added earlier I solved hours ago haven't posted back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this not sure if it's the best but it works.

http://xavisys.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there's some reprocessing going on. Do you have a link to the image, or better yet a link where we can see the markup / CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE6, the grey background will be there because IE6 does not support alpha-transparency in images (without using behaviours or hacks).

This might help:

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Comment: No, I don't know when was the last time I remembered IE6. It doesn't only happen to IE, Chrome and Firefox too. Anyway it's been resolved. Thanks for posting. Pls read the answer I posted.